# Oracle SQL Developer takes long time to connect, run, and disconnect from database when executing stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image: Run Oracle Stored Procedure])

Many of you are already familiar with how to run stored procedure (select a package and pick a sp here to run) using this UI. As I need to get the time to run a stored procedure, I put a bit of additional information in here.

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE();
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(to_char(systimestamp, 'FF6');
-- Actual calling --
MY_SP(
   I_INPUT1 => I_INPUT1,
   O_OUTPUT1 => O_OUTPUT1
);
--------------------
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(to_char(systimestamp, 'FF6');
```

Once I press the OK button, these statements would show (*in the Log Window*):
[image: SQL Developer Log Window]

At the same time at the DBMS output panel, the start time and end time would show up.

To my surprise, I find out the DBMS reports the stored procedure takes only few seconds or even a fraction of second to run, but the 'Process exited' and 'Disconnecting from database' statement **would not** show up until some 16 (or even more) seconds later. (FYI: I use a stopwatch to count the time it takes for those 3 statements to appear in log window.)

Why is that? Anyone has any idea? Does it related to load of database server? Too many simultaneous connection? I have heard that the database is in AWS. Does it matter?

I have tested another stored procedure in the same package, it does not suffer the same.

Comment: are you debugging or executing? if executing i'm not sure why you'd see a connect and disconnect message as neither of those happen while just executing pl/sql with SQL Developer

Comment: Even I am new to Oracle, I believe I am executing. I open a package and right click to select Run. I see that PL/SQL dialog box. I select a stored procedure. Once I click OK button, the *Log* window (View menu -> Log) shows up and say that 3 statements (connect to db, process exit, and disconnect from db). (Question is updated to show the log window.) FYI: I use SQL Developer version 4.2.0.17.089.

Comment: yeah you're right, my bad. there are various reasons why it can take a long time to close a connection - clean up of temp space and all kinds of other things

Comment: Jeff, thanks for answering. After a bit of investigation, I find out it is one of the select causing the slowness. I have `SELECT columnA, .., column D, (SELECT ActiveTime, DoneFlag, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ActiveTime DESC) ... ` I comment the `select... rank() over` and the (perceived) time taken is really short. Eventually I just rewrite the query.

Answer (score 0):

When I post this question, I don't intend to answer myself as I have totally no idea on what is going on. Now I know what is going on. I hope my answer will be helpful for others.

### Problem

When I run a stored procedure using UI, the Log window (View -> Log) will come up. First it says 'connecting to database'. Then after about 16 seconds, the second statement 'process exit' and third statement 'disconnect from database' come up. It seems the SQL Developer takes a long time to execute the stored procedure. My next move, naturally, is to investigate SQL statements in my stored procedure.

### SQL

When I comment out the `SELECT...RANK OVER`, the time taken is reduced from 16 to 1.2 second.

```
SELECT a.columnA, a.columnB, 
....
, CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM (SELECT ActiveTime, DoneFlag, ID
                  FROM (SELECT ActiveTime, DoneFlag, ID,
                        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ActiveTime DESC) RM
                        FROM MAM) t
                  WHERE RM = 1
                  AND t.ID = a.WIN_ID AND t.DoneFlag = 'Y'
                 )
            ) > 0
 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS RECEIVE_STATUS
 FROM ...
```

I rewrite the SQL:

```
PROCEDURE myProcedure (
    ... )
AS
    V_ID     MAM.ID%type;
BEGIN
    SELECT ID
    INTO V_ID
    FROM (SELECT ActiveTime, DoneFlag, ID,
          RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ActiveTime DESC) RM
          FROM MAM) t
    WHERE RM = 1 AND t.DoneFlag = 'Y';

    OPEN P_RETURNCUR FOR
    SELECT a.columnA, a.columnB,
        ...
    , CASE WHEN V_ID = a.WIN_ID THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS RECEIVE_STATUS
    FROM ...
```

### Explanation

The `SELECT... RANK OVER` and `RM = 1` actually pulls out one row from MAM table and this row **does not change** regarding a.WIN_ID. So I extract that part of SQL out. Run it and store value into V_ID. I just need to compare the V_ID with each a.WIN_ID. Done.